# FirebaseUI import: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

I would want to add FirebaseUI dependecy in order to be able to authenticate my users using Google account, E-mail/Password authentication, etc.

Thus I added the dependency, as indicated in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui).

However, I get the following error.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'

    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
}
```

Question: How to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.0'
```

> I would want to add FirebaseUI dependecy in order to be able to authenticate my users using Google account

If you want to authenticate users using Google, you also should also add into your dependecies, the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

Please also make sure to have in your `build.gradle` (Project) file, the following versions for Gradle and Google Services:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: It's weird that IntellijIDEA didn't propose me the 4.3.0 rather than the 4.1.0 version.

Comment: Hi there, if this file is not in version control, then will all developers have to manually do this fix for the checked-in code to build OK? Is there no way to make a change to project files itself?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have latest dependencies for firebase libraries and google play services 
you can check here 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180523

if that  doesn't work then add at the bottom of your gradle:
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true